# readin an image

Tags: c, image, opencv

I am tryint to read an image with OpenCV 2.1 (started just today), C++ using the code below.
I can not see what is the problem in the following. Thank you if you can provide some help.

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
int height,width,step,channels;

//Load the image and make sure that it loads correctly
IplImage* im = cvLoadImage("kermit.jpg", 1); 
if(!im )
{
    //Drop out if the image isn't found
    cout << "Failed to load: "<<"kermit.jpg"<<"\n";
return 0;
}
else
{
    cout<<"Image was loaded with success "<<"kermit.jpg"<<"\n";
return (0);
}

height=im->height;
width=im->width;
step=im->widthStep;
channels=im->nChannels;

cout<<"(height, width)"<<height<<width<<"\n";


cvNamedWindow("kermit.jpj",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

cvShowImage( "kermit.jpg", im );
cvWaitKey(0);
cvDestroyWindow ("kermit.jpg");

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't tell us what the problem really is, I want to point out the following code:

```
if(!im )
{
    //Drop out if the image isn't found
    cout << "Failed to load: "<<"kermit.jpg"<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
else
{
    cout<<"Image was loaded with success "<<"kermit.jpg"<<"\n";
    return (0);
}
```

This means that **if the loading fails you quit the application**, and **if the loading succeeds, you also quit**. Sounds wrong, right? You shouldn't `return` on success.

**You don't need the `else` block**, so please remove it and try again. The rest of the code seems to be OK.

Comment: In that case, please select my answer as the official. Just click on the checkbox near the answer. See you around.